# Databind in MVVM for loosely binded classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM and have situation like this: Lets say I have two loosely coupled classes:

```
public class Client
{
public string Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Adress {get; set;}
public string AccountId {get; set;}
}

public class Account
{
public string Id {get; set;}
public string BankName {get; set}
public string AccountDescription {get; set;}
}
```

where Client.AccountId == Account.Id

in my .xaml.cs I have:

```
public partial class BankingView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private ObservableCollection<Client> Clients {get; set;}
private GlobalAccounts Acounts {get; set;}
//geting data methods and other stuff
}
```

GlobalAccounts is just a singletone helper class containing ObservableCollection of Acounts and some other helping methods making sure it's updated from API when it needs to be, but for simplicity, lets just say it looks like this:

```
public class GlobalAccounts : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Acount> Acounts {get; set;}
    //methods to update Acounts
}
```

in xaml I have the simple ListBox that should display all the Clients and the BankName/BankDescription of every client:

```
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Clients, ElementName=uc}" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Text="Name:" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Adress:" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Adress}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="BankName:" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text={Binding ?????? BankName} Tooltip={Binding ?????? AccountDescription} />
                                                                            
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Limitations: Can't use Converter. Need to use ViewModel

ElseWhere in the program I have situations where I need to get BankName/AccountDescription from other Objects that too have property AccountId.

From my knowledge the ViewModel should look something like this:

```
public class ClientAccountsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string AccountId {get; set;} //Account Id that needs to be matched
    public GlobalAccounts Accounts {get; set;} //singletone of all the Accounts
    public Acount CorrespondingAccount {get; set;} //account coresponding to client
    //logic that would find the Corresponding account based on SelectedClient set/changed
}
```

Question: how this type of ViewModel should be added and called from my .xaml.cs/.xaml and how the bindings should look like?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Is BankingView supposed to select a client out of a collection of all clients? Why does it need to know about accounts? The view model model should know the relation between client and accounts.

Comment: BankingView suppose to Display all the Clients and select the coresponding Account based on AccountId of that Client and display the Account information accordingly.

Comment: That sounds odd. It should only select a client, and the corresponding account(s) should be selected by the view model. The control (or some other control) could then display the selected account.

Comment: Different data is stored in different APIs. Client and Account are just related because they have relationship: Client.AccountId == Account.Id. That's it.

Comment: Sure, that is a relation that should be managed by a view model.

Comment: I think I might be a bit dense, but how something like that should look like?

Comment: The view model would have (at least) three properties (that are used as binding sources in the view), a collection of all clients, the selected client, and a collection of the client's accounts. A ListBox in the view would have its ItemsSource bound to the clients collection, and its SelectedItem bound to the selected client property. If the latter changes, the view model would find all accounts that match the selected client's ID, and update the collection of accounts. Another element  in the view would bind to the accounts collection.

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstood my question. The thing I'm trying to achieve is: instead of seeing Name:foo , Adress:fam, BankName:2556512 in ListBox I want to see: Name:foo, Adress:fam, BankName: Bank of America. OnSelectionChanged - I open entirely different unrelated to this question view. This situation shouts: Converter and I have it implemented with it, but I was asked to use ViewModel instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that *view* model classes shouldn't be what you call "loosely coupled" in this case. They should model the view, hence the name.

So if you want to display the `BankName` of an account of a `Client`, you should create a view model of `Client` that has either a `BankName` or `Account` property to bind to.

In other words; if you are currently binding to some domain object, you should create another class that wraps this object's properties and adds whatever properties that the view needs to bind to. That's what a view model is for after all.

It's the responsibility of the helper class or the view model of the `ListBox` to instantiate these "child" view model objects.